# Facing Fatal error with my Elementor website Fatal error: Access level to Molla_Element_Section::get_html_tag() must be protected

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

The Error my website displays is below:

> Fatal error: Access level to Molla_Element_Section::get_html_tag()
> must be protected (as in class Elementor\Element_Section) or weaker in
> web.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/molla-core/elementor/elements/section.php
> on line 3668

As per the directory above the code on line 3668 is below:

```
/**
 * Get HTML tag.
 *
 * Retrieve the section element HTML tag.
 *
 * @since 1.0
 */
private function get_html_tag() {
    $html_tag = $this->get_settings( 'html_tag' );

    if ( empty( $html_tag ) ) {
        $html_tag = 'section';
    }

    return $html_tag;
}
```

Please help me fix this issue , I tried playing with elementor version (downgraded to check if this was the issue) but didn't help.

Comment: I some how managed to fix this issue temporarily by removing 2 codes from the file and access to my website is regained, the codes i removed from my website are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Object Inheritance in php documentation:
The visibility of methods, properties and constants can be relaxed, e.g. a protected method can be marked as public, but they cannot be restricted, e.g. marking a public property as private.

Most likely Molla_Element_Section class inherits from Elementor\Element_Section and overwrites method get_html_tag. But it uses wrong access level.
get_html_tag method cannot be 'private' it has to be 'protected' or 'public'. As documentation says visibility cannot be restricted.

Comment: But how to fix this, i don't know much about WordPress backend

Comment: change 'private function get_html_tag() ' to 'protected function get_html_tag() ' inside Molla_Element_Section

Answer (score 0):

So I went ahead and rolled back the Elementor version to 3.3.1. Currently, everything works stable and the temporary solution seems working fine. If you are facing the same problem, here is what you need to do to downgrade Elementor.

Login to **WP-Dashboard > Elementor > Tools >** Version Control and Rollback version to **3.3.1**

Click “Save” and make sure to clean the browser cache.
You should get a working website now!